# I'm having some problems getting a Irradiance Map working in Vulkan

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, vulkan

I'm having some problems getting a Irradiance Map working in Vulkan for multiple days.
It seems like the texture aren't stretching to fit the plain it's projected on. I've tried multiple way to figure out how to get the get the full text displayed and nothings working. If the  cube map is 512 x 512 the CubeMap will only show the 512x512 pixels and cut off the rest. And if it's 2048x2048 it shows all of the texture but the rest of it just blank space.

The irradiance part isn't applied here. It just taking the 6 views of the cube and projecting them.

2048 x 2048 view
[image]

512x512 View
[image]

This is irradiance code I've been working with.

```
#pragma once
#include "BaseRenderPass.h"
#include "RenderedDepthTexture.h"
#include "BlinnPhongPipeline.h"
#include "MeshManager.h"
#include "RenderedColorTexture.h"
#include "SkyBoxRenderPipeline.h"
#include "RenderedCubeMapTexture.h"
#include "IrradiancePipeline.h"

class IrradianceRenderPass : public BaseRenderPass
{
private:
    void CreateRenderPass();
    void CreateRendererFramebuffers();
    void SetUpCommandBuffers();

    uint32_t CubeMapSize;
    VkFramebuffer IrradianceMapFrameBuffer;

public:
    IrradianceRenderPass();
    IrradianceRenderPass(std::shared_ptr<VulkanEngine> engine);
    ~IrradianceRenderPass();

    std::shared_ptr<RenderedCubeMapTexture> RenderedCubeMap;
    std::shared_ptr<IrradiancePipeline> irradiancePipeline;

    void RebuildSwapChain();

    void Draw();
    void Destroy();
};
```

```cpp
 #include "IrradianceRenderPass.h"
#include "GraphicsPipeline.h"
#include "Skybox.h"


IrradianceRenderPass::IrradianceRenderPass() : BaseRenderPass()
{
}

IrradianceRenderPass::IrradianceRenderPass(std::shared_ptr<VulkanEngine> engine) : BaseRenderPass()
{
    CubeMapSize = 512.0f;
    RenderedCubeMap = std::make_shared<RenderedCubeMapTexture>(RenderedCubeMapTexture(glm::ivec2(CubeMapSize)));

    CreateRenderPass();
    CreateRendererFramebuffers();
    irradiancePipeline = std::make_shared<IrradiancePipeline>(IrradiancePipeline(RenderPass));
    SetUpCommandBuffers();

    Draw();

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex];
    VkFenceCreateInfo fenceCreateInfo{};
    fenceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FENCE_CREATE_INFO;
    fenceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    VkFence fence;
    vkCreateFence(VulkanPtr::GetDevice(), &fenceCreateInfo, nullptr, &fence);
    vkQueueSubmit(VulkanPtr::GetGraphicsQueue(), 1, &submitInfo, fence);
    vkWaitForFences(VulkanPtr::GetDevice(), 1, &fence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
    vkDestroyFence(VulkanPtr::GetDevice(), fence, nullptr);
}

IrradianceRenderPass::~IrradianceRenderPass()
{
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::CreateRenderPass()
{
    std::vector<VkAttachmentDescription> AttachmentDescriptionList;

    VkAttachmentDescription CubeMapAttachment = {};
    CubeMapAttachment.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    CubeMapAttachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    CubeMapAttachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    CubeMapAttachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
    CubeMapAttachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
    CubeMapAttachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
    CubeMapAttachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    CubeMapAttachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
    AttachmentDescriptionList.emplace_back(CubeMapAttachment);

    std::vector<VkAttachmentReference> ColorRefsList;
    ColorRefsList.emplace_back(VkAttachmentReference{ 0, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL });

    VkSubpassDescription subpassDescription = {};
    subpassDescription.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
    subpassDescription.colorAttachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(ColorRefsList.size());
    subpassDescription.pColorAttachments = ColorRefsList.data();

    std::vector<VkSubpassDependency> DependencyList;

    VkSubpassDependency FirstDependency = {};
    FirstDependency.srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    FirstDependency.dstSubpass = 0;
    FirstDependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    FirstDependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    FirstDependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    FirstDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    FirstDependency.dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
    DependencyList.emplace_back(FirstDependency);

    VkSubpassDependency SecondDependency = {};
    SecondDependency.srcSubpass = 0;
    SecondDependency.dstSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL;
    SecondDependency.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
    SecondDependency.dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    SecondDependency.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
    SecondDependency.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;
    SecondDependency.dependencyFlags = VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT;
    DependencyList.emplace_back(SecondDependency);


    const uint32_t viewMask = 0b00111111;
    const uint32_t correlationMask = 0b00111111;

    VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo createInfo{};
    createInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_MULTIVIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    createInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    createInfo.pViewMasks = &viewMask;
    createInfo.correlationMaskCount = 1;
    createInfo.pCorrelationMasks = &correlationMask;

    VkRenderPassCreateInfo renderPassInfo = {};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_CREATE_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(AttachmentDescriptionList.size());
    renderPassInfo.pAttachments = AttachmentDescriptionList.data();
    renderPassInfo.subpassCount = 1;
    renderPassInfo.pSubpasses = &subpassDescription;
    renderPassInfo.dependencyCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(DependencyList.size());
    renderPassInfo.pDependencies = DependencyList.data();
    renderPassInfo.pNext = &createInfo;

    if (vkCreateRenderPass(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->Device, &renderPassInfo, nullptr, &RenderPass))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create GBuffer RenderPass!");
    }
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::CreateRendererFramebuffers()
{
    SwapChainFramebuffers.resize(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->SwapChain.GetSwapChainImageCount());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->SwapChain.GetSwapChainImageCount(); i++)
    {
        std::vector<VkImageView> AttachmentList;
        AttachmentList.emplace_back(RenderedCubeMap->View);

        VkFramebufferCreateInfo frameBufferCreateInfo = {};
        frameBufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.renderPass = RenderPass;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.attachmentCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(AttachmentList.size());
        frameBufferCreateInfo.pAttachments = AttachmentList.data();
        frameBufferCreateInfo.width = CubeMapSize;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.height = CubeMapSize;
        frameBufferCreateInfo.layers = 1;

        if (vkCreateFramebuffer(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->Device, &frameBufferCreateInfo, nullptr, &SwapChainFramebuffers[i]))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to create Gbuffer FrameBuffer.");
        }
    }
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::SetUpCommandBuffers()
{
    CommandBuffer.resize(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->SwapChain.GetSwapChainImageCount());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->SwapChain.GetSwapChainImageCount(); i++)
    {
        VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
        allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        allocInfo.commandPool = EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CommandPool;
        allocInfo.level = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
        allocInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;

        if (vkAllocateCommandBuffers(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->Device, &allocInfo, &CommandBuffer[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate command buffers!");
        }
    }
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::RebuildSwapChain()
{
    irradiancePipeline->Destroy();

    vkDestroyRenderPass(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->Device, RenderPass, nullptr);
    RenderPass = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

    for (auto& framebuffer : SwapChainFramebuffers)
    {
        vkDestroyFramebuffer(EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->Device, framebuffer, nullptr);
        framebuffer = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    }

    CreateRenderPass();
    CreateRendererFramebuffers();
    irradiancePipeline->UpdateGraphicsPipeLine(RenderPass);
    SetUpCommandBuffers();
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::Draw()
{
    VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo{};
    beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
    beginInfo.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

    if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex], &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
    }

    std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
    clearValues[0].color = { {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f} };
    clearValues[1].color = { {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f} };

    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo{};
    renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
    renderPassInfo.renderPass = RenderPass;
    renderPassInfo.framebuffer = SwapChainFramebuffers[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->ImageIndex];
    renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = { 0, 0 };
    renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent.width = CubeMapSize;
    renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent.height = CubeMapSize;
    renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
    renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();

    vkCmdBindPipeline(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, irradiancePipeline->ShaderPipeline);
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, irradiancePipeline->ShaderPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &irradiancePipeline->DescriptorSet, 0, nullptr);
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    static_cast<Skybox*>(MeshManagerPtr::GetMeshManagerPtr()->GetMeshByType(MeshTypeFlag::Mesh_Type_SkyBox)[0].get())->Draw(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex]);
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex]);

    if (vkEndCommandBuffer(CommandBuffer[EnginePtr::GetEnginePtr()->CMDIndex]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
    }
}

void IrradianceRenderPass::Destroy()
{
    irradiancePipeline->Destroy();

    BaseRenderPass::Destroy();
}
```

Comment: Is your target image larger than the source image? It's hard to judge just by the source, but if that's the case, it may be the culprit.

Comment: I just checked the ColorTexture, RenderedTexture, RenderedCubeMap, The VkRenderPassBeginInfo extent, VkFramebufferCreateInfo's width and height, and of the texture copy logic. All of them are the same size.

Comment: hmm, got it working with a multiview now to create the skybox. But still having the same problem.